# django-cms template(s) as a plugin

Tags: django, templates, placeholder, django-cms

How should look the .py files for just placing template to placeholder?
lets say i just want to use template language but that template should be posted as a plugin.
I understand how the urls dispatcher works (if it would be needed), i'm just confused about views and models files since i don't want to touch code inside django or anywhere else apart from apps directory.

I use zc.buildout with django recipe so just using it as a plugin is crucial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's easily solved using generic views simple: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template